# Why doesn't the tabulary shrink to \linewidth?

Tags: tables, tabulary

Why doesn't the first column shrink to ensure that the table width equals `\linewidth` in the `tabulary` table below? (I am aware that I could use e.g. `tabularx` for this, but here I want to use `tabulary`.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\begin{document}
  \noindent\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}[t]{
    @{}
    L
    c
    c
    p{0.4\linewidth}
    c
    c
    @{}
  }
    \toprule
    A & B & C & D & E & F \tabularnewline
    \midrule
    a a a a a a a a a a a a a a & b & c & d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d & eeeeee & ffffff \tabularnewline
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabulary}
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: How is this different than replacing the `p` column with `L`? Not sure why that actually works.

Comment: @daleif The `p{0.4\linewidth}` column should not be flexible, but be exactly `0.4\linewidth` wide :-) My intention was that the all the flexibility should come from the first/`L` column.

Comment: it is a bug, see https://github.com/davidcarlisle/dpctex/issues/38. If you change the p to m it works.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer that isn't how you spell feature.

Comment: @FredrikP if you modify tabulary.sty as in the above github issue (that is, change 4 to 6 in two places) does your real document work? it would be good to have confirmation that change doesn't break things...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The change is described a bit too tersely for me to know what to do.

Comment: copy tabulary.sty to the folder with your document (from somewhere like `/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tabulary/tabulary.sty`  and then change lines 275 and 369  changing `<4` to `<6` in each case

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Then it, as far as I can tell, just works.

Comment: @FredrikP thanks, I'll try to sort out an update